# Wrong image listing in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a situation in my android app for displaying list of users with their images.

**Situation**
After loading the activity i fetch list of users from server and show them in recycler view. For each image's of user i first check whether image is downloaded, if yes then i take image from cache otherwise download from server. After download i show the image

**What's Happening**
Images which are available on the cache sets fine but for the user's whose image is not available Other user's image sets in there. After scrolling up and down correct image sets. I guess this is because of behavior of recyclerview as it doesn't create same number of instance of view holder as many items are there in adapter.

Below is how I'm setting image in my view holder

```
if(ProfileUtility.localProfilePicExists(user.getProfileImageName(), itemView.getContext())) {
            Log.v(Constant.TAG, "Showing Profile image in small user card");
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(ImageUtil.getLocalImageUri(itemView.getContext(),"circle_"+user.getProfileImageName()+".png")).fit().centerCrop().into(this.imgProfile);
        }
        else {
            ProfileUtility.loadProfilePicture(user.getProfileImageName(),this,itemView.getContext()); // this requests download the image and "this" is used to call "complete" method of this view holder where i load image
            PixyfiSession.save(user.getProfileImageName(),imgProfile); //here i save the image view in which i have to show the image
        }
```

"complete" method

```
public void complete(Object o) {
        if (this.progressDialog != null && this.progressDialog.isShowing())
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(o instanceof ImageDetails) {
            ImageDetails id =(ImageDetails) o;
            if(id.getLocalName() != null && id.getId().equals(user.getProfileImageName()) ) {
                String key = id.getId();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) PixyfiSession.get(key);
                Log.v(Constant.TAG, "Showing Profile image in small user card from complete with name:"+"circle_"+id.getLocalName());
                Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(ImageUtil.getLocalImageUri(itemView.getContext(), "circle_"+id.getLocalName())).into(imgView);
            }
        }
}
```

Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: If the image is not yet available you should set a default -place holder- image. Or a null bitmap.